# Is truth value well-defined?

Tags: logic

I know how to assign truth values to $P\wedge Q, P\vee Q, P\Rightarrow Q, \lnot P$ for atomic propositions $P$ and $Q$. However, I think the truth values of quantified propositions are non-trivial.

How do you prove that every proposition in mathematics, e.g., every proposition in the ZF, has a truth value?

Comment: We can't determine the truth value of every proposition. In theory, then, in some "models" of ZF, the statement is true, and in some models it is false. Whether we can determine the truth or falsehood doesn't affect propositional logic. In the first order logic of a ring, $1+1=0$ is not decidable because some rings it is true, some rings it is not,

Comment: According to Gödel's incompleteness theorem, there are propositions that can neither be proved nor disproved in ZF. (Provided ZF is consistent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the notion of a truth value is hardcoded in the theory. Every theory that concerns itself with logic, provides a different notion of what a truth value is, how to calculate it, etc, if such a notion exists at all. There is even a case where a certain proposition cannot attain any truth value.

This goes beyond the scope of the question, so I will just mention it.
Truth values need not be two in quantity. They can be any amount, finite of infinite. Also, they need not behave as we are comfortable seeing them. So for example, we could have 3 truth values, $ \{ a , b , c \} $, and arrange them in such a way that $ P \cup \neg P $ does not hold. For more information on this, look up Kripke models as semantics for intuitionistic propositional logic.

In such a logic, absurdity (falseness) *is an atomic proposition*, denoted $ \bot $, and by definition can never attain any truth value.